# QT version flexible configuration via props-files in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, qt

I have few projects which uses different QT versions. Qt extension for VS by default uses $(DefaultQtVersion) macro, which value specified in HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Digia/Versions. So, If I use few instances of VS, I can use only one QT version for all solutions in them. Moreover, after switching between solutions, I shouldn't forget to switch QT version, because build with another QT version means rebuild.

I have found a way to specify different Qt versions for each project.
It is possible to change version in .vcxproj

```
<ProjectExtensions>
  <VisualStudio>
    <UserProperties Qt5Version_x0020_Win32="$(DefaultQtVersion)" Qt5Version_x0020_x64="Qt_5.4.1_x64"/>
  </VisualStudio>
</ProjectExtensions>
```

So, I decided to use .props-file with QTADDIN property, for changing version in one place instead of changing in each project every time I changing QT version.

```
<PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros">
  <QTVERSION>5.4.1</QTVERSION>
  <QTADDIN32>Qt_$(QTVERSION)_x32</QTADDIN32>
  <QTADDIN64>Qt_$(QTVERSION)_x64</QTADDIN64>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and in project file:

```
<ProjectExtensions>
  <VisualStudio>
    <UserProperties Qt5Version_x0020_Win32="$(QTADDIN32)" Qt5Version_x0020_x64="$(QTADDIN64)"/>
  </VisualStudio>
</ProjectExtensions>
```

Also, I have added appropriate QT versions in qt-addin, but it does not work. 
"There's no Qt version assighed to this project for platform..." message shows all the time.

Seems, like properties does not work inside ProjectExtensions tag.

Is there are any possibility to change QT version in such flexible way?